# Como elimino palabras,caracteres alfanumericos de una celda de un DataFrame de Pandas?, es un archivo de 8000 mil filas aproximadamente x 8 columnas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ciencia-de-datos

[[image: La Columna de nombre abcd es la que necesito eliminarle textos y valores alfanumericos que aprezcan en esta, es un archivo que concatene de excel, con unos unos APU , ANALISIS DE PRECIOS UNITARIOS PARA PRESUPUESTOS, 140 APU (Hojas de excel que quedaron en una unica hoja de 8000 filas X 8 Columnas, aproximadamnete) , esto lo hago ya que necesito multiplicar esa columna por otra y me genera un error por ser tipo object ][1]]
La Columna de nombre **abcd** es la que necesito eliminarle textos y valores alfanumericos que aprezcan en esta, es un archivo que concatene de excel, con unos unos APU , ANALISIS DE PRECIOS UNITARIOS PARA PRESUPUESTOS, 140 APU (Hojas de excel que quedaron en una unica hoja de 8000 filas X 8 Columnas, aproximadamnete) , esto lo hago ya que necesito multiplicar esa columna por otra y me genera un error por ser tipo object

Comment: Puedes usar la librería [re](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) para crear una expresión regular que aplicar a la columna de tu dataframe y quedarte solo con los números. Solo debes tener en cuenta si admites números decimales o no porque entonces tendrás que identificar el separador decimal y el separador de millares